# My cat stopped eating, drinking, and getting up to go to the bathroom

Tags: cats, health

My 2 year old cat stopped eating, drinking, and doesn't get up to go to the bathroom. I'm taking him into the vet in the morning. Are there any suggestions on what I should and shouldn't do to help him until then? I am unsure what to do.

Comment: Keep him as comfortable as possible and allow him access to fresh water.  Restrict him to one room of the house, do not let him outdoors. It's not uncommon for sick cats to run away.

Comment: Is he eliminating at all? Like on himself? If so, try to gently clean him up, so he's not licking or self-cleaning his poop. If you're keeping an eye on him and trying not to go anywhere you may have an extra set of panties and a maxi pad you could temporarily use for one night (when you're sleeping. Do you think this is a good or poor recommendation @YvetteColomb ? If you have a cat bed or can make a bed with towels, this may help to keep him warm and comfortable.

Comment: @ChristyB. I wouldn't be putting panties on him, it will only distress him. Other than that, checking on him and keeping him clean is good advice.

Comment: how is he today?

Answer (score -2):

Sounds like sickness to me. If he is not cleaning it might be that he´s too overweight to, or just the sickness part again.
Cats are clean instinctively.

Comment: this answer is not helpfull,99%reading the first four words in the header of the question knows the cat is sick.

Comment: @trondhansen Okay. But be nicer about it. It seems like everyone on this website are complete jerks.

Comment: i am sorry but you dont answer the question about what to do to help the cat in the time before the owner can bring the cat to the vet.everybody here want to help the pets and their owners in the best way possible the answers may be short as long as they are helpfull for the ones asking them.on questions like this when a cat stop eating the only advice is to go to the vet but here the op asks if there is something she or he can do to make it easier for the cat before a visit to the vet is possible.

Comment: unhelpful answer.